# How do I get the value entered in an "Input box" to be assigned to a variable?

Tags: jsxgraph

I have created an input box on a JSXGraph and I can type into the box. In the context, the user will enter a number.
How do I assign the entered value to a variable so that I can then do a calculation with it?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use .Value() function to get the value entered in an input like:

```
var input = board.create('input', [0, 1, 'sin(x)*x', 'f(x)='], {cssStyle: 'width: 100px'});

var result = input.Value();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response - I had already found this, but when the input box is changed by the user (student), what is stored in "result" is not updated to the new value in the 'input'.

Comment: Or, if it is changing what is in "result", I don't know how to 'see' the new value.